# Is it OK to encourage a user to add the question in their first language in the comments?

Tags: discussion

Lets be honest. English isn't the first language of many of our users and as a result there are now several language specific sites, for example in [Portugese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/). However, it will take some time till there are SOs in every language, and I doubt that every language ever will be covered.

Now, one *could* argue that today one should learn English, and be somewhat proficient, at least to the point that one can communicate without problems. But overestimation of one's own capabilities leads to… [interesting results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284165/is-doing-so-much-more-work-worth-the-lack-of-feeling-that-you-are-doing-the-aske).

The linked question is completely beyond comprehension, and at that point not salvageable, unless OP explains his intent a little bit better. With a little bit of imagination (and a big bottle of scotch), one can fathom an interesting gem inside that inscrutable post, which is a pity. And OP tries to clear things up, with mixed results.

Given OP's previous posts on SO, I got to the conclusion that his first language is German. Now, I know a little bit of German, and others might too, which brings me to this post's title:

**Is it OK to encourage a user to add the question in their first language in the comments?** After all, the comments are meant to **clear things up**.

If it's possible to do so in another language, great. If no one speaks Unicornian, well, that's a pity, but it's still better than reading only botched English.

---

**EDIT**: To clear things up: SO has a [Non-English Question Policy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/), which is fine. This discussion is about *temporary* inclusion of another language in either the question or comments. The policy allows only the second. Either way, the community shouldn't be responsible to translate questions. It's just meant as an additional way clarify things, especially if the question has been closed as *unclear*.

Comment: I've seen it done in the comments (I swear I even read a post recently _on meta_ about it), and **the comments seem like the right place to do it**. But I have no idea if it's _encouraged or even recommended_.

Comment: How about to take it to chat?

Comment: As long as you clear up the question in English, I don't see the harm in using the comments in this manner. Just don't file any bugs you might have when using the comments in a language other than English. Also, it should be "...explains his intent a little..." not "...explains his intend a little..." ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Waaaaaaah. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [What to do if a new user asks a question in another language?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94657) Somewhat related: [Should multilingual posts be edited to remove non-English content?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109048)

Comment: Non English posts will never receive the same moderation as English posts as only a subset of Stack Overflow users will be able to perform these vital tasks - and for that reason alone - I disagree. However I do think comments explaining that English is a second language for the poster are a good idea.

Comment: @rene: Hm, that's one way. However, chat takes 20+ reputation, whereas a comment (up to 600 characters) can be read by many and doesn't require any rep at all.

Comment: @MattCoubrough: Oh shoot. I meant __temporarily__. Not permanent. Given that there's the "Non-English Question Policy", the question itself isn't really suitable.

Comment: I feel like if there's a question and you're able to guess that OP's native tongue is a language you know, it's totally fine to ask them to post a comment in their language, provided you then translate it and edit it into the original post.

Comment: @Zeta Temporary changes of language of an actual question  (as opposed to comments) run the risk of the post becoming something of a chameleon question with meaning being lost in translation -  A user *could* try and post both an English and Non-English version, but then there is the very real problem that both versions may not express exactly the same thing, making any answers in the worst case nonsensical. Would answers to Non English posts also temporarily be in the poster's native language and then later translated back into English?

Comment: @MattCoubrough: Good point. Lets forget the "temporary question text" at all.

Comment: I think @rene has it spot on. Asking in comments adds unnecessary noise to the question - I think taking it to chat is the best place, you can communicate with the user in whatever language you're both comfortable with, and make any edits required.

Comment: Well, the OP wasn't very thrilled with your approach.  Assuming the brick was supposed to make sense.  Indeed very incoherent, the only thing I got is that he really wanted to talk about something else but didn't want to use direct words to say what he really meant.  Meta does tend to be unfriendly quickly when we all suck.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's actually a German saying, literally translated. It's more common as "People who live in glass houses shouldn't throw stones." or "Those who are vulnerable should not attack others". It's a direct response to another proverb __I__ posted (literally translated, to imitate his style). Since this felt like mockery, I deleted my comment some time later. My comment also contained an encouragement to post the question in German in a comment and spawned this question. Either way, I doubt that the question will see another day.

Answer (score 12):

No, you shouldn't encourage people to add questions on Stack Overflow in any language other than English. If they can't formulate their question in English, they're not likely to understand answers written in English, just as the vast majority of the rest of the community is not going to get much use out of questions and answers in German.

Comment: Well, there's a __big__ difference between active and passive vocabulary. Even though they cannot write a proper English question, they might understand a proper English answer.

Comment: Das ist doch gar nicht freundlich...

Comment: @Zeta This is an English language site. The vast majority of users here wouldn't understand a question written in German.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough. It's about __temporary additions__. That being said, Josh's links brought me to http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/, so Non-English question text isn't feasible. But what about __(temporary) comments__?

Comment: @Zeta You're still left with answers they're probably not going to understand. I don't think anyone is going to stop you, but I don't think the resulting posts are going to be very useful.